# Named Credentials create APIs missing Label and Name values?

Tags: metadata, connected-apps, namedcredentials, connect-api

I'm looking at these three pieces of documentation:

- The [ConnectApi.NamedCredentials](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.242.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_NamedCredentials_static_methods.htm) class and specifically the `createCredentials` method
- The [ConnectApi.CredentialInput](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_connectapi_input_credential.htm) class that defines the argument for the `createCredentials` method
- The [Named Credential](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_named_credential.htm) REST API that supports a POST so presumably can create a Named Credential and is probably what is wrapped by the above Apex classes

and do not see in any of them the ability to set a **Label** or **Name** (that can be set through the Setup UI).

What am I missing here?

**PS**

Trying an `instanceof` reports:

> Operation instanceof is always false since an instance of ConnectApi.CredentialInput is never an instance of ConnectApi.NamedCredential

and calling `createCredentials` with a valid `externalCredential` resulted in this message saying a `UserExternalCredential` is being created which is not what I'm looking for (well I guess the method name and documentation are vague here):

> ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: The UserExternalCredential object couldn't be saved because it's associated with an external credential with the following authentication protocol: Oauth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My conclusion here is that the `ConnectApi.NamedCredentials` class is not designed to create `NamedCredential` or `ExternalCredential` records but is designed to allow `ExternalCredential` records to be read and probably `UserExternalCredential` records to be created.