# Creating a Named Credential with Apex

Tags: apex, namedcredentials, connect-api

Trying to programmatically create a **Named Credential** and getting odd errors when trying to run this code:

> ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: Provide only the developer name of the external credential.

If I comment out the line where I set request.developerName, I get:

> ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: Specify the developerName field in the request payload.

```
ConnectApi.NamedCredentialInput request = new ConnectApi.NamedCredentialInput();

request.masterLabel = 'Metadata API';
request.developerName = 'MetadataApiNamedCredential';
request.type = ConnectApi.NamedCredentialType.SecuredEndpoint;

  ConnectApi.NamedCredentialCalloutOptionsInput calloutOptions = new ConnectApi.NamedCredentialCalloutOptionsInput();
  calloutOptions.generateAuthorizationHeader = true;
  calloutOptions.allowMergeFieldsInBody = true;
  calloutOptions.allowMergeFieldsInHeader = true;

request.calloutOptions = calloutOptions;

  String baseUrl = URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm();
  String apiVersion = '59.0';

request.calloutUrl = baseUrl + '/services/Soap/m/' + apiVersion;

  ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialPrincipalInput principal = new ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialPrincipalInput();
  principal.principalName = UserInfo.getUserName();
  principal.principalType = ConnectApi.CredentialPrincipalType.PerUserPrincipal;
  principal.sequenceNumber = 1;

  List<ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialPrincipalInput> principals = new List<ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialPrincipalInput>();
  principals.add(principal);

  ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialInput externalCredential = new ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialInput();
  externalCredential.authenticationProtocol = ConnectApi.CredentialAuthenticationProtocol.OAUTH;
  externalCredential.developerName = 'MetadataApiCredentialInput';
  externalCredential.masterLabel = 'Metadata API Credential Input';
  externalCredential.principals = principals;

  List<ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialInput> externalCredentials = new List<ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialInput>();
  externalCredentials.add(externalCredential);

request.externalCredentials = externalCredentials;
ConnectApi.NamedCredential namedCredential = ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.createNamedCredential(body);
```

Any thoughts about what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked this? -https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/399701/named-credentials-create-apis-missing-label-and-name-values

Comment: Thanks for this link. Not sure I agree with Keith C's conclusion that the ConnectApi.NamedCredentials class is not for creating Named Credentials because it has a method called createNamedCredential().

Comment: FYI, I ended up using the REST/JSON over the [tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_namedcredential.htm) because I couldn't get an Apex API to work after putting a few hours of work in. Salesforce are pragmatic on how complete the support is for the less used APIs. The good thing about the REST/JSON API is we know it works and is pretty complete because various dev tools use it, but frustrating to have to resort to that.

Comment: Arg... was hoping to put together a post installation config page for System Administrators so they wouldn't have to manually change the Connected App configuration. Seems there will be no way to do what I need from Apex unless I have them add a Named Credential and Auth Provider which adds even more work.